# Setup Apache 2.2 With SNI Under Ubuntu 8.04

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, sni

I am trying to setup SNI on a server running Ubuntu 8.04 with openssl 0.9.8g and apache 2.2.8.  I know that I need either mod_gnutils or openssl 0.9.8j (I think) to support SNI.  Is it possible to do this under Ubuntu 8.04 without having to recompile apache?  If not, I think I would feel better just upgrading my server to 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNI for Apache 2.2 requires OpenSSL with tlsext support compiled. This is done since the OpenSSL 0.9.8g-10ubuntu1 package shipped with Intrepid (8.10), which is not available for Hardy via backports.

So you either switch to 10.04 or recompile from the Intrepid source package. I would personally suggest upgrading to Lucid.

References:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/184131
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/186844
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/apache-tls-sni

Comment: Ideally, I would upgrade to 10.04. However, I am on a tight deadline and don't have the luxury of being able to test everything I should before upgrading a production server.  I was able to compile libgnutls and mod_gnutls and get SNI setup. However, I am having issues with IE and Chrome on Vista and I'm not sure if it's my implementation or not (http://serverfault.com/questions/162836/windows-vista-wrong-certificate-with-sni). If it is, I may end up having to upgrade anyway.

Comment: If a custom-compiled mod_gnutls works for you, that's certainly a good way to go.